# pyhon send data to bigquery returns a field mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

i'm using python and pandas to push data to BigQuery. The script works well but I have an error:

```
object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int
File "/**/bq.py", line 71, in post
job = self.client.load_table_from_dataframe(df,
File "/**/tobq.py", line 99, in <module>
bq.post(data, target_table="tablemane")
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: object of type <class 'str'> cannot be 
converted to int
```

I understand the error but there is no way I can localize it, both my data, `df.dtypes` and the BQ schema look coherent.
Ex (here I'm trying to push only one single line)

my code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df['crawl_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['crawl_date']).dt.date
    df['r_index'] = df['rank_index'].astype('float')
    df['v_index']=df['visibility_index'].astype('float')
    df['s_var']=df['serp_var'].astype('float')
    df['kd']=df['kd'].astype('float')        
    df['camp_id'] = df['camp_id'].astype('int64')        
    print(df.head())
    print(df.isnull().sum())
    
    table_id = f"{os.getenv('GCP_DATASET_NAME')}.{table_name}"
    
    print(df.dtypes)
    df.to_gbq(destination_table=table_id, table_schema=schema_path, project_id=os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT_NAME'), if_exists='append')
```

my data:

```
[{'crawl_date': '2021-03-22', 'domain': 'www.example.com', 'categ': 't1', 'position': 1, 'position_spread': 'TOP_5', 'position_change': 0, 'v_index': 100, 'r_index': 100, 'estimated_traffic': 101881, 'traffic_change': 0, 'max_traffic': 0, 'device': 'desktop', 'top_rank': 1, 's_var': 0, 'kwd': '****** pro', 'volume': 461000, 'kd': 0, 'camp_id': 2, 'camp_name': '******'}]
```

`print(df.dtypes)`

```
crawl_date            object
domain                object
categ                 object
position               int64
position_spread       object
position_change        int64
v_index     float64
r_index           float64
estimated_traffic      int64
traffic_change         int64
max_traffic            int64
device                object
top_rank            int64
s_var             float64
kwd               object
volume                 int64
kd                   float64
camp_id                int64
camp_name             object
```

Finally, my BQ schema:

```
[
{
   "name": "crawl_date",
   "mode": "NULLABLE",
   "type": "DATE",
   "description": null,
   "fields": []
 },
 {
    "name": "domain",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
 },
{
    "name": "categ",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
   "fields": []
  },
 {
    "name": "position",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
 },
 {
    "name": "position_spread",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
{
    "name": "position_change",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
 },
 {
    "name": "v_index",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
 },
 {
    "name": "r_index",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "estimated_traffic",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
   "fields": []
  },
 {
    "name": "traffic_change",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
 {
    "name": "max_traffic",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  }, 
  {
    "name": "device",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
   "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "top_rank",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  }, 
 {
    "name": "s_var",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "kwd",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "volume",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "kd",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
   },
  { 
    "name": "camp_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "description": null,
    "fields": []
  },
  { 
     "name": "camp_name",
     "mode": "NULLABLE",
     "type": "STRING",
     "description": null,
     "fields": []
  }
]
```

Comment: My guess is that BigQuery isn't accepting as string as input for a DATE. BigQuery does some data type coercion automatically, but won't automatically coerce everything. In those cases, you need to cast the data to the desired type yourself. Checkout the documentation on  Conversion Rules: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your crawl_data from an object to a date-time object before sending  to big query.

```
import pandas as pd

df['crawl_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['crawl_date'])
```